# Drop caps resulting in different letter height in Firefox

Tags: css, layout, browser, drop-cap

My entire website looks nice on Chrome. When I tested it in Firefox however, I noticed the height of the drop cap is too high. Examine the good positioning height left in Chrome, and the way too high positioning on the right in Firefox:

Chrome:    . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  . .           Firefox:

[image]   . . . . . [image]

```
column:first-of-type p:first-of-type:first-letter{/* Drop Caps */
    font-size: 3.4em;
    margin: 0 0 -0.1em 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 .75em;
    line-height: 1em;
    float: left;
}
```

What can be tweaked here just for Firefox specifically to bring the height back a little, making it mimic the Chrome rendering?

I don't care about the other differences, I just want the black letter on Firefox to be a little lower.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: I have provided the shortest possible relevant code! Your suggestion would unnecessarily complicate the question. My question is simply about wether there is a way (if so, how) to change the height of an element in only a specific browser (in this case Firefox) without changing anything in other default browsers.

Comment: Please provide a runnable snippet - otherwise we have to guess/work out backwards your HTML structure. It is easy for you to do (use the <> when you edit the question) and  it makes it so much easier to provide an accurate answer.

Comment: I've just tried a simple drop cap in FF and Edge/Chrome (all on Windows10) and I do not get the problem, The code you have given so far is *not* enough to demonstrate the problem. Please create a runnable snippet that does show the problem.